# How do package files .deb files that are installed outside the package tree get put into the normal package tree?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

So, I've installed .deb files through double click or through dpkg, and I was wondering how do they get into the normal package tree structure you can get from apt-get synaptic etc.

I mean, if you install on purpose an older or newer version of a package, or a package that is not yet in the repositories but may soon be, what consequences and behavior to expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference really compared to the packages you install from various repositories.

You can list such packages from Synaptic by selecting *Origin -> Local*.

Answer (score -1):

For the record, the "package tree" your refer to are typically called repositories (repos). If it is from Launchpad, it is called a PPA.

If you install an older version of a package manually (download a .deb file and install it with `sudo dpkg -i`), then the high-level package managers (`apt-get`, `aptitude`, Synaptic, the system update manager, etc.) will prompt you to update to the latest version of the package.

If you install a newer version of a package not in the repos, nothing (else) will happen. Since the version installed is higher than the highest version in any repo, the high-level package managers will consider it "up-to-date". When a version higher than the one you installed becomes available, the package managers will prompt you to update to the latest version. Note that if the version in the repos gets a security update and the version number is still less than the version you have installed, you will **not** be notified of it in any way, since your version is higher than the existing version.

If you install a package not in the repos at all, then there won't be much of an impact, except that you can manage it from a package manager. (In this case, "manage it" would mean that you can remove/purge it, since that the only action available for such packages.)